How do i install and use foundry in windows?
i tried installing it on windows but it's giving me an error stating the command is not recognized.

It installed properly on wsl but when i close and reopen the terminal on wsl, then try to run foundry with foundryup, I'll get this error: Command 'foundryup' not found but everything will work when i reinstall from begining on wsl.
please help how do i get this up and running on windows or wsl without having to reinstall each time i want to use it

You can refer to this part of the Solidity Smart Contract Development course video, in which they've gone through the setup of WSL and Foundry installation in Windows.
If you want to learn more about the Web3 development in Windows, then you can watch the WSL Crash Course for Smart Contract Developers: Master Linux & Web3 Tools in 2 Hours video.

thank you, the you tube video is very helpful, though I have resolved the issue

Great. You're welcome. Happy coding!
